# Reading file and constructing dictionary

Tags: python

i am trying to read a comma delimited file and convert it into a dictionary so that it ends up in the following format

```
{'CpE' : CSE 2315,'CpE' : 'CSE 2320'. 'CpE' : 'CSE 2441'..........,'CS' : CSE 2315, 'CS' : CSE 2320}
```

so all i want to do is store each line in a dictionary with the degree being the key, and the class being the value

the file being read is

```
CpE,CSE 2315
CpE,CSE 2320
CpE,CSE 2441
CpE,CSE 3320
CpE,CSE 3442
CpE,EE 2440
CpE,MATH 1426
CS,SE 2315
CS,CSE 2320
CS,CSE 3320
CS,CSE 4303
CS,CSE 4305
CS,CSE 4308
CS,MATH 1426
```

the code i wrote to try to do this is... fp being the file

```
majors = {}
    for line in fp :
        (degree, course) = line.strip().split(',')
        majors[degree] = course
    print majors
```

what i get is

```
{'CS': 'MATH 1426', 'CpE': 'MATH 1426'}
```

it seems its only grabbing the last value of each degree/key. why?

Comment: Keys in a dictionary are unique... So are you after (CS + MATH) -> 1426, or for CS, a list of MATH 1426, SE 2315, etc....

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries only map a single value to each key. What you should do here is map a *list* of courses to each key.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're assigning it to the same key. You need to use a unique key for each value in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

A key can map to only one value in a dictionary. As a result, you are constantly overwriting the *single* course for each major.

If you want to make a dictionary that maps each degree to a `list` of courses, you can easily do this using collection's `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> majors = defaultdict(list)
>>> fp = open("file.txt")
>>> for line in fp:
...     (degree, course) = line.strip().split(',')
...     majors[degree].append( course )
... 
>>> majors
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'CS': ['SE 2315', 'CSE 2320', 'CSE 3320', 'CSE 4303',
                                   'CSE 4305', 'CSE 4308', 'MATH 1426'],
                            'CpE': ['CSE 2315', 'CSE 2320', 'CSE 2441', 'CSE 3320',
                                    'CSE 3442', 'EE 2440', 'MATH 1426']
                           })
```

Comment: You can do this with the built in dict as well.